# Is a question about the sound and ease of use of a specific harmonica model on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently bought on impulse an harmonica, however i'm wondering how good it is in terms of sound and ease of use considering i plan using it to learn to play, but i'm not sure if this would be on topic.

I already googled it and besides shopping pages the only advice i found is on terms of "its the one you have, so use it" which is not a helpful answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you suggesting a question like "What are the qualities of sound and playability of {harmonica model x}?"

That might be okay, unless it's too localized. If it's a widely-known model of harmonica, it's probably fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how much would be too localized?

Comment: It's tricky. I am not an expert on harmonicas, so I can't say; in order to pass judgement on that, we'd need someone who -is- knowledgeable on the topic to tell us whether it is useful or too obscure.

Comment: I added it to the main site, let's see how it goes.